FlaskSQLAlchemy - Why are my tables not being created upon initialization?
So I'm creating a real time chat application and I want to add authentication for my users. The problem is when I attempt to add a new user to my database I receive the following error "sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: Users".
server.py
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
from models import Users
from db import db

app = Flask(__name__) # Initialize flask app
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///users.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="*") # Initialize SocketIO
db.init_app(app)  
 
def create_tables():
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()

# Catch client layer's emitted message
@socketio.on("message")
def handleMessage(data):
    print("User connected: Value " + data)
    socketio.emit("received_message", data) # Pass user msg to all clients

@app.route('/api/users', methods=['POST'])
def add_user():
    data = request.get_json()
    new_user = Users(name=data['userName'], email=data['userEmail'])
    db.session.add(new_user)
    db.session.commit()
    return jsonify({'message': 'User added successfully!'}), 201

if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_tables()
    socketio.run(app)

models.py
from db import db

class Users(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)

db.py
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

This error is very confusing to me because I have imported the Users table from models.py and I've also included the "db.create_all()" function with respect to my app. My database is being created because "users.db" is being generated as an empty file, but it should also be creating my table and storing my users and it is not. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.
